# What is the probability of following Mutually Inclusive Event?

Tags: probability

There is a pack of 52 cards. Two cards have to be drawn simultaneously without replacement.
What is the probability of getting one Face and one queen?

Face cards are J, Q, K only i.e. 12 Face cards in deck.

My understanding:

**Case I:** Card 1 is Face and Card 2 is queen.
**Case II** Card 1 is Queen and Card 2 is Face.

Answer: P(Case I) + P(Case II)

For P(Case I):

Sub-case 1: Face is a Queen
P(Sub-case 1) $= \frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51}$

Sub-case 2: Face is not a Queen
P(Sub-case 2) $= \frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{51}$

P(Case II) is going to be same as P(Case II).

Therefore final Answer is: $= 2 \cdot (\frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51} +  \frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{51})$

Am I Correct? I will be very grateful if someone can explain my fault in depth, if there is.

Comment: At the very least you have forgotten to subtract $P(\text{Case I and Case II})$ in your first line. Also, would drawing double queen be considered a "good" hand? Because then I would consider the approach $$P(\text{both are face})\cdot (1-P(\text{no queens}\mid \text{both are face}))$$

Answer (score 0):

In case “one queen” means “exactly one queen and one (other) face” there are $\binom{8}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}$ possibilities out of $\binom{52}{2}$.  If it means “at least on queen”, just add $\binom{4}{2}$ possibilities.

Comment: Yes it means "at least one queen" and other can be "any face". But how is it (8C1 * 4C1) + 4C2 ? Can you please explain by elaborating different scenarios.